# Normal distribution - What should be value of $x$ if the company wants no more than $0.5\%$ of the packets to be underweight?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, problem-solving, standard-deviation, means

> A cereal machine is sending $x$ grams of cereal into each packet. The value of
> $x$ is programmed into the machine and the packets are then filled
> with the weight of cereal in each being normally distributed with:
>
> - mean of $x$ grams and
> - standard deviation of $1.8$ grams
>
> The machine is used to fill packets that will be labelled as
> containing $500$ grams. What should be the value of $x$ if the company
> wants no more than $0.5\%$ of the packets to be underweight?

I'm not quite sure how to start this question but here's what I am thinking so far. Do we have to set up some sort of simultaneous equations here since we are only given an unknown mean value of $x$? Does this involve using the standard deviation of $1.8$ grams? Any starting hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let the actual weight of a filled packet be denoted by the random variable $W\sim N(x,1.8^2)$. Then you need to find $x$ so that $P(W<500)\le\frac{0.5}{100}$.

Comment: From your studies you should know how to calculate the p-value of some statistical test. In this case your null-hypothesis is that a packet has less than 500 grams. You wish to reject this, as it's not supposed to happen (more often then 0.5%) . This means your p-value should be lower/equal to 0.5%. Using all of this you can calculate it, using the formulas already provided by Subham Johri above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$$\mathbb{P}[Y<500]\leq 0.5\%$$

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[Z<\frac{500-x}{1.8}\Bigg]\leq 0.5\%$$

$$\frac{500-x}{1.8}=-2.58$$

$$x=504.64$$

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to use the [z-score table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table).  $x$ is the mean of the distribution.  You want less than $5\%$ of the area to be less than $500$ grams.  How many standard deviations does that mean $x$ has to be above $500$ grams?